# How to solve Invalid attribute name error? (possible reason is the colon in the name of attribute)

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, attributes, lxml

Here is actual code:

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.Element("doi_batch", attrib={
               'xmlns': "http://www.crossref.org/schema/4.4.0", 
               'xmlns:xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance', 
               "version": "4.4.0", 
               "xsi:schemaLocation": "http://www.crossref.org/schema/4.4.0 http://www.crossref.org/schema/deposit/crossref4.4.0.xsd"
               })
print(etree.tostring(root, encoding="UTF-8", 
                     method="xml", xml_declaration=True, pretty_print=True))
```

The problem is that some attributes require to have colon in their names, so I'm getting error in output.
Is there any solution for this type of errors?

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: Namespace prefix declarations are not attributes.  See duplicate link for how to add default namespaces and namespace prefix declarations to an element in lxml.

Comment: @kjhughes Thank you very much, it works!